# What does the phone by itself mean?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

You have the green circle which means they are online by computer. Then you have the phone with the number next to it saying how long they've been away.

If the phone is by itself does that mean that the person is currently on Facebook with their mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if the phone is by itself does that mean that the person is currently on Facebook with their mobile device?

Yes, that's pretty much what it means